# Topological space with countable basis, confusion in the definition.

Tags: general-topology

I didn't really understand something : Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ a topological space with countable basis. Let $\mathcal B$ a basis of $\mathcal T$. Does it mean that $\mathcal B$ is countable or that every element of $\mathcal T$ can be written as a countable union of element of $\mathcal B$ ? If $\mathcal B$ is countable, then of course every element of $\mathcal T$ can be written as a countable union of element of $\mathcal B$, but I really don't think that the converse is true, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so if $(X, \tau)$ has a countable basis then there may still be some bases that are not countable. If we let $X$ be the real line and $\tau$ the usual set of open sets then $\tau$ is a basis for the reals, as is the set of all open intervals, but the set of all open intervals with rational end points is a countable basis.

In a general topological space, every set can be written as a union of members of the basis. This need not be a countable union. In the case of the basis given above for the real line (the set of all open intervals with rational end points) then is so happens that every set can be written as a countable union but that is a happy accident.

And answering your last point, you are right, the converse is not true. If we take the set of all open sets as the basis then every set can be written as the union of a single set (itself) but the basis is not countable.

Comment: Just one thing : when you write *In the case of the basis given above for the real line (the set of all open intervals with rational end points) then **is so happens that every set can be written as a countable union but that is a happy accident**.* If a basis is countable, it's not an accident, is it ? For example, let $\mathcal B=\{]a,b[\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$. Then the fact that every open of $\mathbb R$ can be written as a countable union of element of the for $]a,b[$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ is not an accident since $\mathcal B$ is itself countable... so I don't really understand you here..

Comment: Ahhh yes, you are totally right on that one; good point.

Comment: So of course the cardinality (finite or infinite) sets required to write any set as a union cannot exceed that of the basis (in this case countable infinity) but it can come in a long way below. If we use all open sets as the basis then it is $1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

If a space $X$ is *hereditarily Lindelöf* and $\mathcal{B}$ is any base for the space $X$, then any open set $O$ can be written as a countable union of elements from $\mathcal{B}$. 
A space can be hereditarily Lindelöf without there being a countable base for $X$, an example of this is the Sorgenfrey line (or the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$, as Munkres calls it).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that a basis $\cal B$ of $\cal T$ is countable. It means that *there exists* a basis $\cal B$ of $\cal T$ that is countable.

Comment: Ok, and if all open can be written as a countable union of element $\mathcal B$, will $\mathcal T$ have a countable basis ?

Comment: The statements "$\cal T$ has a countable basis $\cal B$" and "$\cal T$ has a basis $\cal B$ and every open set in $\cal T$ can be written as a countable union of elements of $\cal B$" say different things.

Comment: Does the property "All element of $\mathbb T$ can be written as a countable element of $\mathcal B$" has a special name ?

Comment: No, it is not a special property, as $\cal T$ itself is such a basis.